# How do I connect a cog in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I have been trying to make an error handler for my commands (in my main.py file) but I can't seem to find a way to connect a cog and main.py, I have put in a print command to see when the cog is connected but doesn't show, maybe I'm doing it wrong, but I can't find anyway to connect them and it's kinda bugging me.

Here is my cog code

```
from discord.ext.commands import Cog

class brody(commands.Cog, name='brody'):
    pass

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

bot.load_extension('brody')
        
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_ready(self):
print("Brody's cog online")


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):

        if hasattr(ctx.command, 'on_error'):
            return

        cog = ctx.cog
        if cog:
            if cog._get_overridden_method(cog.cog_command_error) is not None:
                return

        ignored = (commands.CommandNotFound, )
        error = getattr(error, 'original', error)

        if isinstance(error, ignored):
            return

        if isinstance(error, commands.DisabledCommand):
            await ctx.send('you can\'t use that, that is disabled')

        elif isinstance(error, commands.NoPrivateMessage):
            try:
                await ctx.author.send('you can\'t use my commands when dming me, try it in a server i\'m in.')
            except discord.HTTPException:
                pass

        elif isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
            if ctx.command.qualified_name == 'tag list':
                await ctx.send('i cannot find that person, probably try someone else or try again')

        else:
            print('Ignoring exception in command {}:'.format(ctx.command), file=sys.stderr)
            traceback.print_exception(type(error), error, error.__traceback__, file=sys.stderr)


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(mycog(bot))
```

And yes I did copy/paste some code from a GitHub tutorial don't judge, but I'm here to find out how I can connect the cog to my main.py file for some crash handler or something so it'll be appreciated to help out I guess, thanks.

Comment: There's a huge amount of things wrong in your code, you should really learn more python and OOP concepts before diving deeper into discord.py

Answer (score 0):

It looks fine, except for the indentation, the `pass` at the beginning of the class, and the `load_extension` call inside the cog. You're supposed to call `load_extension` inside your main file, and pass `load_extension` the relative path of the file you're trying to load. For example, if your cog, let's call it `brody.py`, is in the same folder as your main file, you would use `bot.load_extension("brody")`. See [the docs for cogs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html) for more information.